# How long does Thailand visa (code TR) last and does it allow extension?

Tags: visas, thailand

I got visas from UK embassy for my family to go to Thailand (Category TR, no of entry S).

I am planning on staying for 60 days and then extending for another 30. One thing that worries me they no date by which we are supposed to leave country.

[image]

**Have I selected correct ones (do they allow to stay for 60 days and extend another 30)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Have I selected correct ones (do they allow to stay for 60 days and extend another 30)?

Yes (eg [see](http://www.phuketvisa.com/index.php?lay=show&ac=article&Id=538608335)).

TR is a standard Tourist visa (valid 60 days - can be extended up to another 30 days) and `S` is for single entry.

There is no departure date indicated because that depends upon when you enter (which must be by or on the 30 January 2017 date shown).

---

Courtesy of @Dorothy:

> [7. Extension of Stay](http://thaiembassyuk.org.uk/?q=node/45)
>
> Those who wish to stay longer or may wish to change their type of visa must file an application for permission at the Office of Immigration Bureau located:
>
> Government Centre B,
>   Chaengwattana Soi 7,
>   Laksi,
>   Bangkok 10210,
>   Tel 0-2141-9889
>
> (or at [immigration.go.th](http://www.immigration.go.th/)).
>
> The extension of stay as well as the change of certain type of visa is solely at the discretion of the immigration officer.

Extensions can be applied for in Chiang Mai and Phuket as well.  Chiang Mai has multiple Immigration offices, currently extensions are handled through the Promenada Mall office (ground floor).  Phuket has Immigration offices in Phuket Town and Patong Beach, both of which can handle extensions

Comment: @Dorothy - Thai visas can be extended at Immigration offices in Chiang Mai and Phuket as well (perhaps others).  But as you mentioned, issuing an extension is at the officers discretion, as is the length of extension, 30 days is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Tom and, if you know or have a source, include any suggested time frame in which to request an extension (e.g., when during the visit, how far in advance of current visa expiry).

Comment: I am unaware of any official limits on how far in advance, ie: you can't apply more than 7 days prior to your visa expiring, etc.  But doing it too early (such as few weeks after arrival) might raise questions as to why. The idea behind the extension is for tourists that come, love their visit so much and decide to stay longer, rather than for tourists plotting to get around the 60 day visa. Most folks do it a week or so before their current entry stamp expires.  It is a fairly quick, painless process.